# Run progress bar while switching Activity

Tags: android

im stuck in a situation where i am switching from activity 1 to activity 2.
i am using Thread.sleep(5000) to start another activity after 5 seconds
But the progress bar which i want to run for five seconds also sleeps with the first activity
Pleaze help me as to when i click next Button on first activity a progress bar shoud run for five sec
and then activity should be loaded
My Code is:

```
    public class Activity1 extends Activity  {          
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B);
    final ProgressBar  p=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pr);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
              p.setVisibility(4);
            Thread t=new Thread();
            try{                    
                t.sleep(5000);              

        }
            catch(Exception e){}

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), activity2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

    });   

}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use Thread.sleep() - it is the root to all evil. Instead, use a `Handler` and its `postDelayed( Runnable, time )`-method like below:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity  {          
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B);
  final ProgressBar  p=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pr);
  next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
      p.setVisibility(4);

      final Handler handler = new Handler();
      handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), activity2.class);
          startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
      }, 5000);
    }
  });   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your OnClickListener for this. This will not block your main thread, as you are doing (that explains why your application freezes for 5 seconds):

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        new AsyncTask<Integer, Long, Boolean>()
        {
            ProgressDialog pd;

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params)
            {
                pd = new ProgressDialog(Activity1.this);
                pd.setTitle("Loading Activity");
                pd.setMessage("Please Wait ...");
                pd.setMax(params[0]);
                pd.setIndeterminate(false);
                pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

                publishProgress(0L);

                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long waitTime = params[0] * 1000;
                try
                {
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < waitTime)
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        publishProgress(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... values)
            {
                if (values[0] == 0)
                {
                    pd.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    pd.setProgress((int) (values[0] / 1000));
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
            {
                pd.dismiss();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), activity2.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        }.execute(5);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You better use an AsyncTask for this purpose.Using threads like that in your activity is not proper and can lead to some fails.Check this docs about AsyncTask.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 3):

First of all in the Above code, you need to start the Thread using this.

t.start();

you can also try below code,

```
new Thread ( new Runnable() 
{
        public void run()
        {
           // Place your Intent Code here
        }
}.start();
```