# android - progress black out but still running

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm developing DES decryption in Android platform.

this is my main

```
package com.example.crack;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.crack.MESSAGE";
    public final static String EXTRA_PLAINTEXT = "com.example.crack.PLAINTEXT";
    public final static int ENCRYPTION_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, encryption.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ENCRYPTION_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Check which request it is that we're responding to
        if (requestCode == ENCRYPTION_REQUEST) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String result = data.getStringExtra(encryption.EXTRA_ENCRYPTION_RETURN);

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessage.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, result);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the partial  of my encrpytion

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.encryption);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    message = intent.getStringExtra(Main.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    //Dictionary
    is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.english);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    readDic();

    String result = "";
    try {
        result = decryptBruteForce();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_ENCRYPTION_RETURN,result);
    setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
    finish();

}
```

when i click on the button, it calls the sendMessage function, while it is running the decryption the screen just black out until it finish running.

I had try using progress bar follow this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133118/run-progress-bar-while-switching-activity), but not working, I need a button that can stop the process while running.

And is it possible to set a log on view, which show what the function is doing right now? like what is shown in the IDE log? Example, showing what key is the decryption trying right now.

Or maybe just a progress bar or please wait will do too.

I tried to change the sendMessage to this, yet it still black out and crash

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, encryption.class);
        view.setEnabled(false);
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
                pd.setTitle("Processing...");
                pd.setMessage("Please wait.");
                pd.setCancelable(false);
                pd.setIndeterminate(true);
                pd.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                try {
                    //Do something...

                    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_message);
                    String message = editText.getText().toString();
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, ENCRYPTION_REQUEST);

                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                if (pd!=null) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    b.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }

        };
        task.execute((Void[])null);
    }
```

if I put sleep to 50000, it did not crash, but still it black out.

Comment: and what your log cat show on app crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a Thread and a Handler. While you try each combination, you update the progress bar.

```
private int mProgressStatus = 0;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)     
{    
    .... // Other initializations

mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
mProgress.setMax(dictionaryLength);

// Start lengthy operation in a background thread
new Thread(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
     for (int i=0 ; i<dictionaryLength ; i++)
     {
         mProgressStatus = decryptBruteForce(i);

         // Update the progress bar
         mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
             }
         });
     }
 }
}).start();
}
```

However i recommend you to use AsyncTask to do background operations while you need to update the UI to show the progress or info about whats going on.

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Its a good habit to add a cancel control in your loop, so you can finish it from outside of the AsyncTask (for example another button in you UI).

```
private class DecryptTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {  
 protected Long doInBackground(String... words)   
 {   
     long wordsDecrypted = 0;   
     for (int i = 0; i < words.length ; i++) {   
         wordsDecrypted += decryptBruteForce(i);   
         publishProgress(i);   

        // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) 
            break;
     }
     return wordsDecrypted;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     mProgress.setProgress(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Decrypted " + result + " words");
 }
}
```

And you can cancel the AsyncTask from outside with the cancel method:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)

PD: Codes are not tested, just examples to show how it works